# Mac Open File dialog and using Find to search for files — Keyboard shortcut to select results without using mouse?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, dialog

For example, in Safari's Open File dialog I can hit Command-F to search for images.

I appear to be forced to use the mouse to select results as the arrow keys don't do it. Only after moving the cursor to the results part of the dialog window am I able to scroll through results with arrow keys and hit enter to open an item.

I want to do this all with the keyboard and no mouse. Is there not a keyboard shortcut to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access:...

By default it will be set to Text boxes & lists only. You need to set it to All controls.
It will then be able to Tab through all areas, though it's still not hugely convenient - it may take 3 tabs before it reaches the actual file list, where you can then navigate with the arrow keys.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I'm not allowed to upvote you, so I just wanted to let you know it was appreciated nonetheless.